# How do I fetch a base64 string via an API call

Tags: javascript, base64, fetch

The Fetch API will not run when I try to get a base64 string. What am I missing?

I've tried using a standard fetch in javascript, which is fine on all other calls until it's base64. It doesn't even reach the alert.

```
fetch(vimgurlone)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(dataimage1 => {
   alert("here");
   document.getElementById("theactualdata").innerHTML  = dataimage1.Content;

})
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```

The json response will be something like:

> { Content: "brtergbrtbrtbwrtnhtehrth4t5h......" }

I would like receive and then assign the data to a variable and then display it or at least get to the alert message in the code above. The variable/URL "vimgurlone" is valid and displays a json response when pasted into a browser, but the fetch will not run. Do I need to decode it or something? The base64 string can be quite long. Thanks.

Comment: Is nothing printed out in your console? Also check the network tab to see if anything is going on in there

Comment: can you show your backend code? Is it even returning a base64 string?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me! the issue was the API hadn't enabled cross origin requests, the code above is fine.

Thanks for the suggestions.